# Needed to bring all CSS components in one line

Tags: html, css

I have below components as shown in the picture as they are not in line. I have tried almost all css components but nothing working for me. I am new to CSS. Could any one please help me here.

**Requirements:**

1. The distance between text and first list box needed to be decreased.
2. All components should be in one line.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="cf mpcontent_header">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="with_button" style="font-size: 18px">@Resources.LanguageStrings.WOIndexHeaderViewAll</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 hidebtnmobile">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedVendor, Model.GetVendorList(user.idCompany, user.SiteSelection), new { data_placeholder = Resources.LanguageStrings.SelectVendors })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="submitButton" class="btn large primary-bg" style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);return false;">@Resources.LanguageStrings.ClearAll</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 hidebtnmobile">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStaff, Model.GetStaffMembers(user.idCompany, user.SiteSelection), new { data_placeholder = Resources.LanguageStrings.SelectStaff })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="submitButton" class="btn large primary-bg" style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="selectAllComboItems('#SelectedStaff', false);return false;">@Resources.LanguageStrings.ClearAll</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 hidebtnmobile" style="float: right;">
                @if (!user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.Viewer | SystemRoles.Submitter | SystemRoles.Tenant | SystemRoles.StaffLimited ))
                {
                    <button id="multiComplete" class="btn large primary-bg button_float_right " style="font-size: 12px;" title="@Resources.LanguageStrings.MultiComplete">@Resources.LanguageStrings.MultiComplete</button>
                }
                @if (!user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.Viewer | SystemRoles.Submitter | SystemRoles.Tenant | SystemRoles.StaffUnlimited | SystemRoles.StaffLimited | SystemRoles.VendorUnlimited | SystemRoles.VendorLimited))
                {
                    <button id="multiClose" class="btn large primary-bg button_float_right " style="margin-right: 10px; font-size: 12px;" title="@Resources.LanguageStrings.MultiClose">@Resources.LanguageStrings.MultiClose</button>
                }
        @if (!user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.Viewer | SystemRoles.VendorLimited))
        {
                    @*<button id="add" class="btn large primary-bg button_float_right hidebtnmobile" style="margin-right: 10px;" title="@Resources.LanguageStrings.AddWOTitle" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddWorkOrder")'"><i class="glyph-icon icon-plus"></i>@Resources.LanguageStrings.Add</button>*@
        <button class="btn large primary-bg button_float_right btnPrint hidebtnmobile" style="margin-right: 10px; font-size: 12px;" title="@Resources.LanguageStrings.PrintTitle ">@Resources.LanguageStrings.MultiPrint</button>
        }
            <div class="tableActions">
                <button class="btn large primary-bg" onclick="copyTableText($('#WorkOrderList'));">Copy</button>
                <button class="btn large primary-bg" onclick="$('#WorkOrderList').tableToCSV();">CSV</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use `flex` to get the same.

Comment: give us a clean [mcve] please. Here's your code with bootstrap - it's a mess and doesn't look like your screenshot. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BZbXPK

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
<div class="col-md-3 hidebtnmobile">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedVendor, Model.GetVendorList(user.idCompany, user.SiteSelection), new { data_placeholder = Resources.LanguageStrings.SelectVendors })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="submitButton" class="btn large primary-bg" style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);return false;">@Resources.LanguageStrings.ClearAll</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

you are placing the new divs with col-md's that add upto 12 columns without wrapping them in a div with class="row"

whenever you do such an activity you have to first bind it in a div with class="row"

for example this part of your code should be written as:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 hidebtnmobile">
    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedVendor, Model.GetVendorList(user.idCompany, user.SiteSelection), new { data_placeholder = Resources.LanguageStrings.SelectVendors })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button id="submitButton" class="btn large primary-bg" style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);return false;">@Resources.LanguageStrings.ClearAll</button>
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```